# How can I show all possible combinations of "cuts" in a program in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, function

What I have to do is to solve a problem about cutting bars, the user will be asked how many bars does he have and thier length and how many cuts does he want to make and thier length, and then the program will have to calculate the residue of the bars and all the possible combinations of cuts, after the user knows the combinations the should be given like a "ranking" of the cuts depending on the residue of the bars.

For example:

```
Number of bars: 3
Lenght of bar 1: 10
Length of bar 2: 20
Length of bar 3: 30

Number of cuts: 4
Length of cut 1: 5
Length of cut 2: 5
Length of cut 3: 15
Length of cut 4: 20
```

So the possible combinations of cuts would be:

```
Combination 1:   
 Cuts in bar 1: 5, 5 Residue bar 1: 0
 Cuts in bar 2: 20 Residue bar 2: 0
 Cuts in bar 3: 15 Residue bar 3: 15

Combination 2: 
Cuts in bar 1: 5, 5 Residue: 0
Cuts in bar 2: 15   Residue: 5
Cuts in bar 3: 20   Residue: 10

Combination 3: 
Cuts in bar 1: 0 Residue: 10
Cuts in bar 2: 5, 15 Residue: 0
Cuts in bar 3: 5, 20 Residue: 5

Combination 4: 
Cuts in bar 1: 0 Residue: 10
Cuts in bar 2: 15 Residue: 5
Cuts in bar 3: 20, 5, 5 Residue: 0
```

So far I have this code but there are some mistakes when it displays the combinations:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int s, n=0, cont=1, m, i, j, q, a, z;

    System.out.print("Number of bars to be cut : ");
    s = scan.nextInt();
    int b[] = new int[s];

    do{
        System.out.print("Bar's length " + cont + ": ");
        b[n] = scan.nextInt();
        n++;
        cont++;
    }while (n<s);

    System.out.print("Number of pieces to be cut: ");
        m = scan.nextInt();
        int p[] = new int[m]; 

        n=0;
        cont=1;

        do{
            System.out.print("Length of the piece " + cont + ": ");
            p[n] = scan.nextInt();
            n++;
            cont++;
        }while (n<m);

        int bars[][] = new int[s][s];
        int pieces[][] = new int[m][m];

        for (n=0; n<s; n++){
            q=n;
            for (cont=0; cont<s; cont++){
                bars[n][q] = b[cont];
                q++;
                if (q>=s){
                    q = q - s;                    
                }
            }
        }


        for (n=0; n<m; n++){
            q=n;
            for (cont=0; cont<m; cont++){
                pieces[n][q] = p[cont];
                q++;
                if (q>=m){
                    q = q - m;                    
                }
            }
        }

        int auxb[][] = new int[s][s];
        int auxp[][] = new int[m][m];
        int cpb[][]= new int [100][100];

        for (i=0; i<s; i++){
            for (j=0; j<m; j++){

                for(q=0; q<s; q++){
                    auxb[i][q] = bars[i][q];
                }

                for(q=0; q<m; q++){
                    auxp[j][q] = pieces[j][q];
                }

                q=0;
                for (n=0;n<s;n++){
                    for (cont=0;cont<m;cont++){
                        if (bars[i][n]>=pieces[j][cont] && pieces[j][cont]!=0){
                            bars[i][n] = (bars[i][n] - pieces[j][cont]);
                            cpb[n][q]=pieces[j][cont];
                            pieces[j][cont]=0;
                            q++;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                q=0;
                while(q<m && pieces[j][q]==0){
                    q++;
                }

                if (q==m){
                    a=1;
                    z=0;
                    System.out.print("Probability " + i + "," + j + " \n");
                    for (q=0; q<s; q++){
                        System.out.print("Residue of bar " + a + " es: " + bars[i][q] + ", with cuts of ");
                        while (cpb[q][z]!=0){
                            System.out.print(cpb[q][z] + ", ");
                            z++;
                        }
                        System.out.print("\n");
                        a++;
                        }
                    System.out.print("\n");
                }

                else
                    System.out.print("It's not possible to make those cuts \n");

                for(q=0; q<s; q++){
                    bars[i][q] = auxb[i][q];
                }

                for(q=0; q<m; q++){
                    pieces[j][q] = auxp[j][q];
                }

            }
        }

    }
```

How can I make this functional? Thanks

Comment: Could you point out some of the mistakes which are produced by the code?

Comment: That's a lot of code to read, and a lot of effort to understand. I always found reading multidimensional arrays to be a nightmare

Comment: lol Cruncher it's like a hundred lines tops

Comment: It would probably help to split the code into several functions, use more descriptive variable names, and add a comment here and there about what's going on. Not only are you more likely to receive help, you'd also need less, because it would become easier to find mistakes.

Comment: It's more a logic problem than a compiling problem, when the posibilities are displayed some of them are not correct, or just don't appear but they're considered in the rest used to displayed the residue and I also have to make the part of comparing each posibility to rank them

Comment: Look up "bin packing problem".